# Using Google Map View on iOS versus on Android

Tags: iphone, android

on iOS you don't need to specify the Google Map API key. But In android, you do have to specify, so the question why such difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are completely different and the iOS one was written by Apple and directly licensed to them. The license is different.

Obviously features are different too with the iOS version in my opinion being more feature rich.